# python - replace values in url

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a URL like the following -

```
url = "http://servername:8080/api/environment/component.get?query=(name LIKE '%componentname%')"
```

I want to replace the following values with argument parameters I have as strings -

```
servername
environment
component
componentname
```

I want it then to be passed into requests -

```
r = requests.get(url, auth=('domain\user', 'password')
```

The problem is I can't figure out how to replace the values.  I can't do %s, %d because it's possible that the value in %componentname% could start with an s or d which would break the encode.

Comment: Use string.format with { } to escape. You can even use {0} {1} etc to avoid accidental escaping

Comment: I actually did <servername> and then did url.replace('<servername>', 'server')

seems inefficient though to have to have 4 separate url.replace...

Comment: You may want to look into the [`uritemplate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uritemplate) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand the following solution should work for you, and it's more straight forward(It was also sugested in the first comment by user Tim Castelijns):

```
url = "http://{0}:8080/api/{1}/{2}.get?query=(name LIKE '%{3}%')".format(servername, environment, component, componentname)
```

If you want more readability you could even do it like this:

```
url = "http://{servername}:8080/api/{environment}/{component}.get?query=(name LIKE '%{componentname}%')".format(servername, environment, component, componentname)
```

Comment: The second option does not work for me (using python 3.9), actually what works is `"http://{servername}:8080/api/{environment}/{component}.get?query=(name LIKE '%{componentname}%')".format(servername=servername, environment=environment, component=component, componentname=componentname)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's inbuilt string concatenation.

```
url = "http://servername:8080/api/environment/component.get?query=(name LIKE '"+ componentname +"')"
```

It will append number or string as it is and you don't need to take care of %s or %d.

Comment: I tried this with all the replacements and it didn't like it because of the internal '' and the outside ""

Comment: Can you pls clarify. You can always escape internal quotes.

Comment: @whoisearth just use `'` and `"` then. They mix well in python. Example `'this is "a string" that is valid'`